# Regex how to replace \r\n with an actual newline in string

Tags: regex

Because \r\n are "special" chars in a regex I have a problem identifying what I actually need to put in my expression.

basically i have a string that looks something like ...

```
bla\r\nbla\r\nbla
```

.. and i'm looking to change it to ...

```
bla
bla  
bla
```

... using a regular expression.

Any ideas?

Comment: `s/\\r\\n/\n/` What language?

Comment: Please be more specific...Are you working on a plain Text file? Or are you coding in PHP, JAVA etc.??

Comment: i am taking the result of a soap call from a service which is encoded and basically removing the encoding so I can debug the result, but i don't want to "remove it" i need to change the chars in to what they should be.

Comment: i guess i could pull the string in to visual studio and do this with a simple replace string.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n") would be the equivelent i guess (not checked it though) (in C#)

Comment: ok do a search for \\r\\n and replace it with \n

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\` is an escape character in regex and can be used to escape itself, meaning that you can write `\\n` to match the text `\n`.

Use the pattern `\\r\\n` and replace with `\r\n`.

Comment: there's still some oddities but that must be how notepad++ is handling the expression or something (it's like its randomly removing the odd char, there's also a few more newlines than i was expecting so it's obviously matched more than it should have.

Comment: @Wardy What oddities are those? Remember that `\\r\\n` will not match `\r` alone or `\n` alone. Do you have an example string where it did not work as expected?

Comment: it's ok ... it solves my problem at least :) its stuff like "hello world\r\nhello world" is wierdly returning something random like "helo world(actual newline char)hello worl" ... no idea why ... probably a bug in notepad++ but im working on a string that represents the full content of an email so i only need certain key info and this is a quick fix to make it readable nothing more :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need regex for this (unless this is not the only thing you are replacing), but \r\n is the way to go in most variants of regex.

Examples:

- PHP

  - `$str = preg_replace("/\\r\\n/", "\r\n", $str);` or
  - `$str = str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $str);` (or `"\\r\\n"` for the first argument)
- Ruby

  - `str = str.gsub(/\\r\\n/, "\r\n")` or
  - `str = str.gsub('\r\n', "\r\n")`

Comment: yeh i was toying with the idea of pulling it in to Visual studio (since the code im working on was written in C# anyway) but i just wanted to grab the result from the wcf test client and paste it in to notepad++ for examination, the problem is i got \r\n instead of newlines in the test client result lol