# Why replaceAll(...) works with two \\?

Tags: java

I've this text and I need to replace all \r\n with \n.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\r\n

Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus\r\n

et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.\r\n 

Don12345
```

When I test on a Java Regex compiler online, the code 1 doesn't work.

Code 1

```
String result = myText.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n");
```

But this code works:

Code 2

```
String result = myText.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "\n"); //second test
```

And according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18865424/4587985), actually should be four \

Why the code on second test works (code 2)?

**UPDATE**

Actually code 1 works, I'm sorry the mistake.

Code 1
[image: Debug evaluation of code 1]

Code 2
[image: Debug evaluation of code 2]

[image]

So "\r\n" in my text isn't a metacharacter?

Comment: Because replaceAll() returns a string replacing all the sequence of characters matching regex and the replacement string too.

Comment: I just wonder why you do that. It's simpler to do replace("\r", "") then all \r are gone.

Comment: The naming of `String.replace()` and `String.replaceAll()` is really screwed up. Both methods (!) replace all occurences. However, `replace` searches for literal strings and `replaceAll` for regexes. I think the `replaceAll` should have been called `replaceAllRegex` and `replace` should have been called `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the following will work in the intended way with `String#replaceAll`:

```
myText.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "\n")
```

The reason is, `String#replaceAll` expects a regex and in order to escape `\`, you need another `\` but since it's a regex pattern, you need another pair of `\\` (the way you do it e.g. in `\\s`).

It should be

```
myText.replaceAll("(\\\\r\\\\n)", "\n");
```

which means `\r\n` will be replaced with `\n`.

**Alternatively,** you can use [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) which expects the string to be replaced instead of regex as is the case with [String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) i.e. `myText.replace("\\r\\n", "\n")` will work in the same way as `myText.replaceAll("(\\\\r\\\\n)", "\n")` does.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\\r\\n\n" + "\n"
                + "Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus\\r\\n\n" + "\n"
                + "et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.\\r\\n \n" + "\n" + "Don12345";

        System.out.println(myText);

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        String result = myText.replaceAll("(\\\\r\\\\n)", "\n");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\r\n

Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus\r\n

et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.\r\n 

Don12345
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.


Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus


et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.


Don12345
```

Comment: I've debug it and works (I double checked the breakpoint). Also, I needed it bc of this issue (https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/768).. the text has 200 chars  (column is a VARCHAR 200) and a "dataException: data is too long for the column" was thrown. After the replaceAll, the UPDATE works fine on MySQL.

Comment: @DanielaMorais - It means you are not facing any issue. You are just trying to understand something. I shouldn't have answered because your question was not clear.

Comment: @DanielaMorais - I've updated the answer based on your update.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character in regex and can be used to escape itself, meaning that you can write `\\n` to match the text `\n` and `\\r` to `\r`

Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539945/regex-how-to-replace-r-n-with-an-actual-newline-in-string)